# Bootstrap tooltip not appearing onhover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

HTML:

```
<li><a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Falas">Regjistro shpallje</a></li>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
});
```

The tooltip isn't appearing. The `<li><a>` element is in header.
I have all the files linking to document js/cs but it still not working
Any ideas?
After searching stackoverflow for answers I found this.
http://jsfiddle.net/DUPyR/249/

I tried it but it didn't work. 
Anyone knows where the problem?

Comment: any error in the console? also did you add the bootstrap js file

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined index.html:227
(anonymous function)

I get this.

Comment: Looks like jQuery is not included...

Comment: Include `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eEaaD/)

Please ensure you have included

1. `jQuery` script file
2. [bootstrap.css](http://dev.derekmccrone.com/sc2stats/assets/css/bootstrap.css)
3. [bootstrap-tooltip.js](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js)

Comment: 3 of them  are included,still can't figure out what's wrong, the tooltip is not showing.

Comment: Have you included jQuery file multiple times..?  Or Multiple versions of jQuery..? They may conflict..

Comment: Nope, jquery is included only once.

Comment: Fixed it,all I did was to include $(function() {
    $('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
});

in tooltip.js
Thanks.